# Change background whit local hour

Tags: css, background

This code get system hour and change the background image

```
 victorHora = new Date 
if (victorHora.getHours() > 5) {
    Imagem = 'my image. Im not allowed to post link';
} else if (victorHora.getHours() > 18) {
    Imagem = 'my image. Im not allowed to post link';
} else {
    Imagem = 'my image. Im not allowed to post link';
}
</script>
<script>
$('body').css('background-image', 'url( + Imagem + )');
 </script>
</head>
```

But the background don't appears
I think it suck's for this:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url( + Imagem + )');
```

Can you help me?

Note: if i put `document.write(Imagem)`, the link appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly concatenating the string.

This

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url( + Imagem + )');
```

Should be this:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url( '+ Imagem + ')');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Note: i have put this code in wrong archive too, but it works after

Comment: Agora que percebi que você é br. Eu ia postar no pt mas nem sabia que existia. E como faz isso de por a resposta aceita?

Comment: Você já aceitou, era o V embaixo dos votos